# Unable to apply mask in opencv android(Java)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to apply mask on circle or point. i draw circle above lips to apply mustache. but i am unable to replace that with image of mustache. I am not using native. Please help me.

Comment: can you show your code. because what kind of stuff you can do i don''t know.

Comment: yeah sure
` Point center1 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + mouthArray[j].x + mouthArray[j].width * 0.5,
                            facesArray[i].y + mouthArray[j].y + mouthArray[j].height * 0.1);
                    int radius = 3;
                    
                    Imgproc.circle(mRgba, center1, radius, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 4, 8, 0);`

Comment: On this point or circle im trying to apply image of mustache but i cant
 Mat logo =Imgcodecs.imread("/raw/img.png");

                    Mat img1 =Imgcodecs.imread("/raw/abc.jpg");

                    Rect rrr = new Rect(20,40,245,265);

                    Mat imageROI = mRgba.submat(rrr);

Answer (score 0):

this my complete code for the masking of the image please refer it. here may use camera for the masking frame with yellow, green and brown.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    protected CameraBridgeViewBase cameraView;
    protected TextView tvDistance;
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mHSV;

    private Mat red;
    private Mat blue;
    private Mat yellow;
    private Mat green;
    private Mat brown;
    private Mat mask;

    private MatOfPoint matOfPoint;
    private Mat pts;
    private Handler handler;

    int height;
    int width;

    int camera_height;
    int camera_width;

    ArrayList<Float> averageList;
    static int AVERAGE_FACTOR = 3;

    private MenuItem mItemPreviewFeatures;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();

        averageList = new ArrayList<>();

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        cameraView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                camera_height = cameraView.getHeight();
                camera_width = cameraView.getWidth();
            }
        });

        cameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        cameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(new CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
                mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
                mHSV = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
                mask = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

                pts = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                yellow = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                green = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                brown = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                blue = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                red = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraViewStopped() {
                mRgba.release();
                mHSV.release();
                mask.release();
                pts.release();

                blue.release();
                yellow.release();
                green.release();
                brown.release();
                red.release();
            }

            @Override
            public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

                Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 4);

                //red
                //Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(234, 240, 199), new Scalar(234, 240, 104), red);
                //blue
                //Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(110, 50, 50), new Scalar(130, 255, 255), blue);
                //Yellow
                Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(25, 80, 80), new Scalar(36, 255, 255), yellow);
                //Green
                Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(37, 80, 80), new Scalar(70, 255, 255), green);
                //Brown
                Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(10, 80, 80), new Scalar(30, 200, 200), brown);

                // logical OR mask
                //Core.bitwise_or(red, blue, blue);
                //Core.bitwise_or(blue, yellow, yellow);
                Core.bitwise_or(yellow, green, green);
                Core.bitwise_or(green, brown, mask);

                //Imgproc.dilate(mask, mask, new Mat());

                // Find non zero pixels
                pts = Mat.zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());
                Core.findNonZero(mask, pts);

                // Compute bounding box
                matOfPoint = new MatOfPoint(pts);

                try {
                    if (matOfPoint.cols() > 0 && matOfPoint.rows() > 0) {
                        final Rect box = Imgproc.boundingRect(matOfPoint);
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Height : " + box.height + " :: Width : " + box.width);

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                float focalLength = Util.getFocalLength(box.width, 1, 1);
                                float distance = Util.getDistance_2(focalLength / 3, camera_height, box.height);

                                if (averageList.size() > AVERAGE_FACTOR) {
                                    float d = 0.0f;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < AVERAGE_FACTOR; i++) {
                                        d += averageList.get(i);
                                    }
                                    tvDistance.setText(String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", (Math.abs(d / AVERAGE_FACTOR) / 304.8)) + " ft"));
                                    averageList.clear();
                                } else {
                                    averageList.add(distance);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        //Core.rectangle(mask, box.tl(), box.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
                    }

                    Core.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(350, 350), new Point(camera_width - 350, camera_height - 350), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return mRgba;
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView() {
        cameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        tvDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    cameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
        mItemPreviewFeatures = menu.add("Tracking");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item == mItemPreviewFeatures) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (cameraView != null)
            cameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cameraView != null)
            cameraView.disableView();
    }
}
```

Comment: you ask me or explain me. I don't know what you say?

Comment: Well brother im telling you that i copied your code and replaced it with mine but Core.rectangle is showing error and i dont know why can you please tell me that? iam using opencv 3.0

Comment: version number openCV 2.4.9